# How to make Sublime Text 3 treat certain extension as html?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I have a node.js development environment in which templates have `.hbs` extension. I'm wondering how to make them as html for Sublime Text 3, so that I can benefit from markup coloring and tidying etc?

Comment: [so] duplicate: [How to customise file type to syntax associations in Sublime Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8088475)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8104764/727695)

> View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as ...